# Selected Option is not Working in MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm unable to get selected value in dropdown using simple below code -

```
<select class="form-control" id="team-name" name="gameTypes">
    @{long selectedOption = @ViewBag.HomeTeamId;}                                  
    @foreach (var item in Model.teams)
    {
        <option value="@item.TeamId" data-logo="@item.LogoURL" selected="@(selectedOption == @item.TeamId ? "selected" : "")">@item.FullName</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using Html.DropDownListFor??

Comment: Beacause in DropDownListFor I'm able retrieve only text value but in Option value I can retrieve one more data-logo attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

Write your method to get the needed Teams in a `List<SelectListItem>` and then in your controller put the values in a ViewBag (`ViewBag.Teams = GetTeams();`)

For exmaple:

```
[NonAction]
private List<SelectListItem> GetTeams()
{
   IEnumerable<Team> teams = new List<Team>();

   //fill the teams here from the DB

   return teams.Select(team => new SelectListItem
     {
       Text = team.TeamName, //here you can select the property that you want to show as text in the dropdown
       Value = team.ID.ToString()
     }).ToList();
}
```

And in your view, retrieve

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> teams = ViewBag.Teams as List<SelectListItem>;
}
```

And here define your dropdown and pass teams as the datasource:

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TeamId, teams, "Select a team", new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```